# Print only lines different from several strings of a bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following input:

```
/ > blablabla
title 1 
-------
title 2
-------
...
-------
title n
/ >
```

Now i need to read only the lines that contain titles, so i must remove the ------ and / >.
I managed to exclude all the ----- with:

```
if [ "$LINE" != "-------" ]
```

But the problme is to remove the two lines:

```
/ >blablabla
/ >
```

(where blablabla could possible change). I want to exclude all the strings thata start with: "/ >"
But i tried in several ways without success.

With:

```
if [[ $LINE!=/* ]]
```

i had no success. 
What is the correct way to obtain that result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line; do
  case $line in
    '/ >'*|---*)
      continue;;
  esac
  echo "$line"
done << \EOF
/ >blablabla
title 1 
-------
title 2
-------
...
-------
title n
/ > 
EOF
```

Comment: It quite works. The only strange problem is that  the first line (/ > blablablala) was still printed. Any idea?

Comment: I did test this against your pattern ... standby, I will include the entire thing so you can see where it diverged.  BTW, I would also suggest simplifying the first pattern to `/*|---*)`

Comment: i just edited my question to correct a little error on the first line. The correct pattern is / > blablabla (with a space before blabla...).

Answer (score 4):

To iterate over only the titles, you could try the following:

```
grep -vE '^(/ >|---)' your_file.txt |while read line; do 
  # process the titles
  echo $line
done
```

This will exclude the two types of lines that you don't care about.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern='^/ > |^-------'
while read -r line
do
    if [[ ! $line =~ $pattern ]]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done < inputfile
```